# parsing xml data into php variable how

Tags: php, xml

Can any one give me hint with example how to perform following method

```
  $XMLAttendee= "<attendee_list>
    <attendee>
    <attendee_id>1028</attendee_id>
    <screen_name>shahid</screen_name>
    <language_culture_name>es-ES</language_culture_name>
    </attendee>
    </attendee_list>";

   $requestParameters["attendee_list"]=$XMLAttendee;
```

this is how i have to parse xml data into API, so what i want to know is,,,,,how can i create xml file and parse in $xmlattendee variable...

can anyone explain me with example plz...

Comment: There are thousands and thousands of examples here in search and on the net. Google `parsing xml data into php variable`

Answer (score 0):

```
$XMLAttendee= "<attendee_list>
    <attendee>
    <attendee_id>1028</attendee_id>
    <screen_name>shahid</screen_name>
    <language_culture_name>es-ES</language_culture_name>
    </attendee>
    </attendee_list>";    

$xmlarray= new SimpleXMLElement($XMLAttendee);

var_dump($xmlarray); //teach a man to fish and he will eat forever
```

Here is a nice example: http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-To-SimpleXML-With-PHP.html